# How to set right to left direction in RadAutoCompleteBox?

Tags: asp.net, telerik

How to set rtl direction in RadAutoCompleteBox?

```
<div dir="rtl">
     <telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox ID="radAutoBoxUser"  runat="server" EnableLoadOnDemand="true"

                                MinFilterLength="3"
                                InputType="Token" AutoPostBack="false">
                                <WebServiceSettings Method="GetUserList" Path="~/Services/WebService.asmx"></WebServiceSettings>
                                <TokensSettings AllowTokenEditing="True" />
                            </telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some research about this subject because it is quite interesting. 
If you would like direction: rtl it will only work on empty text, and generaly you should use CSS for this: [CSS Skin File Selectors for RadAutoCompleteBox](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/autocompletebox-css-selectors.html)

In the link above you have elements that exist inside the RadAutoCompleteBox.

Now if you would like to have your cursor on the right side of the rad, the you should make simply css class with property `direction: rtl;`

It will give you the possibility to add elements from right to left. Now if you want elements to aligned to the end of the rad box, you need to use css property `float: right`. After this, we can add elements from right to left without any problems.

Full Code:

aspx:

```
<Telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox Width="500" runat="server" ID="RadAutoCompleteBox1" CssClass="myClass" InputType="Token" />
```

css:

```
.myClass .racTokenList .racToken {
    direction: rtl!important;
    float:right;
}
```